# What material should go between old and new concrete?

Tags: concrete

I recently poured a slab for a hot tub and I want to pour additional concrete around it for a walkway.  I want to keep the new concrete separated from the hot tub slab in case they heave at different rates in the winter.  What kind of material would be good to separate them? I've done some looking around but I haven't really found anything. Something like low-density fiberboard?

Comment: Look for "concrete expansion joint" for suitable materials/methods. That's effectively what you are doing, I think.

Comment: I have tried searching for that and all I find is material that looks like weather striping.

Comment: That's what it looks like. Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: Google "pre-formed joint filler", which is a fabric strip placed in between the concretes. You can leave 1/4" - 1/2" on top that is to be sealed later for better looking.

Comment: That is what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @R13 answers go down there, I was thinking a walkway on top of the existing slab , next to a pre cast filler is better for the op’s concerns.

Comment: @Ed Beal I am not familiar with the precast filler, do you have a link to it? That deserves another answer If he's adding concrete topping instead of adjoining.

Comment: I thought adjoining that’s why I deleted my “on top of” answer googling precast / pre formed filler the latex to fiber expansion joint material used between slabs. (I would not use with a walkway) but that’s what the op wanted.

Comment: This is a slab next to another slab.